# Java fails to recognize that I am declaring the subclass and cannot find member method

Tags: java, oop

I made a small toy program to replicate a problem I am having in a larger project. In the following code, class `A` is a parent class from which class `B` inherits. Class `B` adds a new method called `PrintStuff`. In my main method I am declaring class `B` by providing its superclass. I need to do this for reasons related to the real use case:

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.String;

class A {
    String x;

    A(String value) {
        x = value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    void printStuff() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A Binstance = new B("B instance");

        Binstance.printStuff();
    }
}
```

However the program does not compile due to the following:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Library\src\com\company\test.java:28:18
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method printStuff()
  location: variable Binstance of type com.company.
```

Why is Java not able to recognize that in reality I am instantiating an object of class `B`? How can I get the compiler to recognize that a method `printStuff` in fact exists?

Comment: `Binstance` is an `A`, not a `B`. What `Binstance` actually is, is decided at runtime, so the compiler can't guarantee it's a `B`. You'll have to cast it to assure the compiler you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During compilation time we know only that the *Binstance* object is of type **A**, which means it doesn't know anything about the printStuff() method (which you declared in class **B**) and that's why you get that error.

Now, you have two options:

1. You can use a cast

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A Binstance = new B("B instance");

        ((B)Binstance).printStuff(); //casting Binstance to B
    }
   ```
2. You can make class **A** abstract and create an abstract method - printStuff()

   ```
    abstract class A {

        abstract void printStuff();
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`Binstance` is declared as having type `A` and `printStuff()` is not declared in `A`, but in `B`. Only methods of `A` are visible in this case. The method is there, but not visible. To make it visible, declare `Binstance` as `B`.

```
B Binstance = new B("B instance");
Binstance.printStuff();
```

Comment: As I indicated in the question, I need to maintain the declaration using type `A` for reasons related to the actual use case.

Comment: Then you need to declare printStuff() in A or cast Binstance to B when calling printStuff(). There is no other way. This is how Java's type system works.

Answer (score 0):

Note this carefully: when B extends A, all B is an A, but not the other way around.

So in your case, **Binstance** is an A and then can't access the `printStuff` method of B.

To make your code work, you need to **coerce** Binstance to be of type of B; this is called a **cast** in java.

So this should work :   `(A(Binstance).printStuff();`

Happy Coding !